# Why does the VS Solution Explorer Script Documents list keep growing and how do I use those links?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

When we debug an MVC5 application, links are provided to access the running scripts as shown below.  This is for a basic MVC5 application that has had absolutely no modifications:

[image]

If we simply refresh the screen 3 times on the home page, the list displayed gets longer as shown below:

[image]

I've never really tried to debug a script yet.  I have used the html links to view pages and I understand I can open one of the .js files, set a breakpoint and try to debug a script.  But why are there so many links?.  I would have thought I only need a single link for any given script or page that is in progress; that the links would go away when the script or page is no longer active.  Clearly I'm missing something about the constantly growing list.

Could someone provide a brief explanation of this feature and how I will use it.  My book on Visual Studio mentions this feature, but doesn't provide enough text for me to get a handle on this aspect of the feature.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/378796/add-option-to-remove-script-document-item-in-the-s.html)? And similar to [this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351537/provide-a-way-to-prevent-the-script-documents-fold.html). This option has been queued up for prioritization, but maybe there will be some time before the new feature comes, sorry for this inconvenience. If possible,  please vote for the two issues:)

Comment: Thanks.  Unlike others, I didn't particularly see a problem with how it works, I just wondered why?  But are you saying that the extra entries every time we refresh a page are of no value?  And that really, we need only find a line that describes the item we want to look at for debugging and just use that line, which may appear any number of times, but it's really just the same entry repeated?

Comment: The content in the script document usually means the script which is in debug. But I'm not sure which the same files which occur many times mean, on my side, if I open them, always their content is not the same even with the same name. I'm trying to get someone experienced in this topic to help.

Comment: ,Is this when debugging Chrome? Does the same behavior happen when debugging IE?  And do you have iframes in your page?  Can you tell me the URL for the duplicate entries? Can we get that by right clicking on the script name?

Comment: I absolutely can reproduce same issue yesterday. But can't reproduce it any more today, Not sure what change I made(I've done many changes), and perhaps it occurs when some specific behavior? Where(what script) do you set the breakpoint?

Comment: I debug using Edge.  I hadn't spent a lot of time in those links because I didn't have problems requiring that type of debug.  But upon reading you post I checked a few links.  It seems the only links that are valid are the last ones that went up.  The links above appear to be unreliable.  For example, the older .js scripts open like the .html links - that's wrong.  The older .html scripts don't actually show the web page, but rather the sequence of code line last executed.  So it seems as though all the extra lines are not useful, only the most recent lines.  Best I can advise right now.

Comment: Hi, could you share a simple sample here by one-drive, so that I can check it directly. And if we confirm the existence of the issue, we will post it for you.

Comment: Tell me `specifically`, in detail, what you are asking for and I will surely try to help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with web-app debugging, and the issue I found on my side is not the same as you. so I need a simple sample from you to check it. If the same issue(extra links unreliable as you mentioned) can be reproiduced on my side. I think I need to report this issue to product team, which helps improve vs's user experience.

Comment: I have collected a set of files.  Explain how you wish to receive them.

Comment: Thanks Alan, could you share it by one-drive or github link, I would test it and report this issue if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Uploaded, but a warning.  I do not normally use GitHub, so it's not clear to me if I have done this right.  The project at [this location](https://github.com/wheelera/lance/tree/master/BasicMvc5/WebApplication1) includes a [zip file](https://github.com/wheelera/lance/blob/master/BasicMvc5/WebApplication1/4-js%20scripts.zip). The zip file has screen shots of my MVC project, but you will see the same results with the uploaded project.  I also offer in the `0 readme.txt` of the zip file my limited observations.  Please advise that you can access everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alan! The sample and details in the .zip file are accessible and useful. For some reason I can't reproduce the issue on my side.(Not sure if this has sth to do with my vs settings)I have involved someone more experienced at this topic to help research it. Please be patient :)

Comment: Just an update, we've got a fix for the issue. It should be in the next preview release of Visual Studio (16.2 preview 2). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the Edge debug adapter. Specifically, the adapter is supposed to send an event when the page refreshes (or a navigation occurs) to clear out old scripts that are no longer valid for the new execution context ([here's a link](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Events_LoadedSource) to the event description in the debug adapter protocol if you're curious).

We've opened an [issue on the GitHub project](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-edge-debug2/issues/145) where you can track the progress of the fix.

For a workaround in the mean time, if you click on the bottom-most duplicate script in the list, that should be the latest loaded version, and should work without error.

***EDIT**:

We've got a fix for the issue which should be out with 16.2 Preview 2 of Visual Studio.